# Office 365 ProPlus on RDS

Tags: microsoft-office-365, rds

Are there any major gotchas to use Office 365 ProPlus on a 2012 R2 RDS server. It used be tricky but after doing some online research now seems to be fully supported. Just wanted to confirm before I commit to this approach

Additionally do I also need any type desktop virtualization license for each ProPlus user installed on RDS?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you understand your update strategy and that the Office client isn't allowed to do self-updates.

Also, ensure shared computer licensing is set and that each user is licensed in Office 365 with the SAME plan.  You cannot mix Business and Enterprise licenses in RDS.

Comment: I would add as well.  That while online mode is usually preferred for VDI/RDS, with Exchange Online the performance difference can be pretty noticeable.  I would consider using cached mode in Outlook, and setting it to the lowest 3 days cached settings.  If you are not using persistent profiles, you'll need to plan on how to accommodate those OST files.